# Error:error Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: angular4-httpclient

I am trying to bind some JSON data from my API to HTML and iterate it over it using `*ngFor` in angular 4. Unfortunately, I'm getting the error in this question's title.

The code in question:

**countryList.ts**

```
export interface CountryList {
    UserName : string,
    Country : string[],
}
```

**Service.ts**

```
export class LoginServicesService {

  constructor(private o:Http) { }
  functionCountriesList(userName:string)
  {
    return this.o.get('http://localhost:55760/api/Login/GetCountries/'+userName).map((res:Response) =><CountryList[]>res.json());
  }

}
```

**Component.ts**

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private loginService: LoginServicesService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  countries: CountryList[];
  countryValue: number;
  countryName: string;
  GenerateCountries(userName: string) {
    this.loginService.functionCountriesList(userName).subscribe((data) => this.countries = data);
    console.log(this.countries);
  }
}
```

**Component.HTML**

```
<table align="center">
  <tr>
    <td><label id="lblUserName">UserName:</label></td>
    <td><input #userName type="Textbox" id="txtUserName" (keyup.enter)="GenerateCountries(userName.value)" (blur)="GenerateCountries(userName.value)" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <label id="lblPassword">Password:</label>
    </td>
    <td><input type="password" id="txtPassword"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Domain:</td>
    <td>
      <select id= "district" style="width:100%" (change)="selectdrop($event)">
        <option value="NIL">Select Domain</option>
        <option *ngFor="let c of countries;let i=index">{{c}}</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**JSON from api is**

```
{
  "UserName": "hello",
  "Country": [
    "South Africa",
    "Russia",
    "India",
    "America",
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're trying to directly iterate through the result of your API call, which a JSON object as you've pasted. You need to sub-select the "Country" field from your API response first and iterate through that.